# How to use camera inside my App controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I open camera inside my app controller.

I don't want to present built in camera controller.
I want to make my own camera sort of app.

Any suggestion or guide will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use `UIImagePickerController` for this

1. Declare `UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController;` globally for the class
2. Declare protocols

   - `@interface YourClassName : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>`

---

```
imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[imagePickerController setDelegate:self];
[imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[imagePickerController setMediaTypes:@"public.image"]]; //specify image (not video)
[imagePickerController setShowsCameraControls:NO]; //hide default camera controls
[imagePickerController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[imagePickerController setToolbarHidden:YES];
[imagePickerController setAllowsEditing:NO];
[self.view addSubview:imagePickerController.view];
```

---

Use the `takePicture` method for the `UIImagePickerController` object like and assign it on a button action, like:

```
-(IBAction)btnTakePictureAct:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [imagePickerController takePicture];
}
```

Use the delegate `-imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` to get the image.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
}
```

---

*See this, get an idea, make your custom camera controls.

Refer: [UIImagePickerController Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)*

Comment: @AhadKhan : glad it helped but note that this is just a simple example and the _accepted_ way of doing this is by utilizing the `cameraOverlayView` property of the `UIImagePickerController` object and using custom created delegates for the camera actions. When I get time, I'll update this answer